# C++ delete all nodes from binary tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree, tree-traversal

Hey Im writing a binary tree in c++ and have some problems with removing all nodes.
I tried to use the following function for that:

```
void RemoveAll() { RemoveAll(Root); }
void RemoveAll(Node *node)
  {
  if (!node) return;

  RemoveAll(node->Left);
  RemoveAll(node->Right);
  delete node;
  }
```

And my printing functions:

```
void PreOrder() { PreOrder(Root); }
void PreOrder(Node *node)
  {
  if (!node) return;

  std::cout << node->Element << std::endl;
  PreOrder(node->Left);
  PreOrder(node->Right);
  }

void InOrder() { InOrder(Root); }
void InOrder(Node *node)
  {
  if (!node) return;

  InOrder(node->Left);
  std::cout << node->Element << std::endl;
  InOrder(node->Right);
  }

void PostOrder() { PostOrder(Root); }
void PostOrder(Node *node)
  {
  if (!node) return;

  PostOrder(node->Left);
  PostOrder(node->Right);
  std::cout << node->Element << std::endl;
  }
```

The problem is that if I run a printing function afterwards to see if the nodes are really deleted I get an Exception which tells me that the given node was `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF7`. Any ideas why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `void RemoveAll() { RemoveAll(Root); Root = nullptr; }`? or `void RemoveAll(Node *&node)` and setting `node` to `nullptr`.

Comment: The head node's memory was deleted but it was never set to NULL.

Comment: Thank you very much! setting Root to nullptr worked.

Comment: In C++ use `nullptr`. In C you use `NULL`.

Comment: @tadman Yeah, already knew that but thank you anyways! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Jarod42 and 0x499602D2 who provided the answer.

The final solution looks like this for all future users who have the same problem:

```
void RemoveAll() { RemoveAll(Root); }
void RemoveAll(Node *&node)
  {
  if (!node) return;
                     
  RemoveAll(node->Left);
  RemoveAll(node->Right);
  
  delete node;
  node = nullptr;
  }
```

Comment: It should be `delete node; node = nullptr;` not how you wrote it. You are leaking memory right now.

Comment: @TanveerBadar Oh you are right, sorry for that mistake!